# Ruby throws data exception in macOS

Tags: ruby, macos

### The Objective:

Write a Ruby program to replace a single line in a text file.

### The Problem:

Ruby throws an exception regarding the data in my text file when I run the program in Terminal in macOS 10.12. Specifically, the message is: *myprog.rb:3:in `block in ': invalid byte sequence in UTF-8 (ArgumentError).* The program works fine for about 30 lines of data until it hit a line in the data that contains a copyright symbol © encoded as a single byte with the value 0xA9.

### The Data:

In Terminal, the **file** command shows *"ISO-8859 text, with CRLF line terminators"* Detail: The data file is a script for **Inno Setup**, was written in **Inno Setup Compiler**, and that program is happy with it. My Ruby program is intended to make a copy of the original for debugging purposes.

### The Program:

```
fname = '/Users/Vacuumhead/Documents/Temp/myscript.iss'

File.foreach(fname) { |line|
    if line =~ /^OutputDir/
        puts 'OutputDir=Y:\\Users\\Vacuumhead\\Temp'
    else
        puts line
    end         
}
```

### What I've Tried:

I changed `foreach(fname)` to `foreach(fname, 'r:iso-8559-1')`. Then I got the same runtime error on the very first line of data. In essence, things got worse.
I also tried running the first version of my Ruby program in **Windows 7**, and that worked just fine, so ultimately I have accomplished what I had set out to do, and at this point the question is really just academic. But I'm particularly keen to understand why a Ruby program that runs in Windows doesn't run in **macOS**, and what could be done to fix it for macOS.

Comment: Did you try `File.foreach(fname, :encoding => 'iso-8859-1')`?

Comment: @Casper I did now. That worked. Thanks!